# JavaFx: How to update hours on the basis of difference b/w two times?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, jfoenix

I'm developing an application in **JavaFx** in which I'm using **jfoenix library** and **Java 8 Time**. In my application I've two **TimePickers** and one **TextField**. All nodes are initially **set to 11:00** like this:

[image]

What I want is whatever the **difference between** the **TimePickers**, let say if **Time1** is **9:00 AM** and **Time2** is **11:00 AM**, so the **difference** will be **2**, so **add 2 hours** to the value which is already present in the **TextField** that is **11:00**, so it'll become **13:00** and if user change the **Time2** to **10:00 AM** so now **difference will be 1** so **add 1 hour** to the **initial value** of **TextField** which was **11:00** **(not to the new value which is currently 13:00)** and make it to **12:00**. Please help me how can I achieve.

In my current code the problem is that it's updating on the basis of new value (e.g if 13:00) not on the basis of initial value (e.g which is 11:00) that's if current value is 13:00 and difference is 1 so it's making it 14:00 not 12:00 :-

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTimePicker;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class SampleController {

    @FXML
    JFXTimePicker tp1;
    @FXML
    JFXTimePicker tp2;
    @FXML
    TextField tf1;

    public void initialize() {
        tp1.setValue(LocalTime.of(11, 00));
        tp2.setValue(LocalTime.of(11, 00));

        tf1.setText("11:00");
        tf1.setEditable(false);

        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        update(tp1.getValue().toString(), tp2.getValue().toString(), tf1.getText(), tf1);

        tp1.valueProperty().addListener(listener);
        tp2.valueProperty().addListener(listener);

    }

    public void update (String t1, String t2, String tf, TextField textField) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        LocalTime parseTime1 = LocalTime.parse(t1,format);
        LocalTime parseTime2 = LocalTime.parse(t2,format);

        long diffT1AndT2 = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(parseTime1, parseTime2);

        LocalTime parseTime3InTextField = LocalTime.parse(tf,format);
        LocalTime add = parseTime3InTextField.plusMinutes(diffT1AndT2);
        tf1.setText(add.toString());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way will be to store the initial value of the the tf1 text field and pass that initial value and not the updated value everytime to the update method.

```
public void initialize() {
        tp1.setValue(LocalTime.of(11, 00));
        tp2.setValue(LocalTime.of(11, 00));

        String tf1Text = "11:00";   // added the initial value 
        tf1.setText(tf1Text);
        tf1.setEditable(false);

       /*Passing the initial String here instead of the updated value */
        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        update(tp1.getValue().toString(), tp2.getValue().toString(), tf1Text , tf1);  

        tp1.valueProperty().addListener(listener);
        tp2.valueProperty().addListener(listener);

    }

    public void update (String t1, String t2, String tf, TextField textField) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        LocalTime parseTime1 = LocalTime.parse(t1,format);
        LocalTime parseTime2 = LocalTime.parse(t2,format);

        long diffT1AndT2 = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(parseTime1, parseTime2);

        LocalTime parseTime3InTextField = LocalTime.parse(tf,format);
        LocalTime add = parseTime3InTextField.plusMinutes(diffT1AndT2);
        tf1.setText(add.toString());
    }   
}
```